# How can I obtain traffic statistics information for QWebEngine

Tags: c++, qt5, qwebengineview

On the developer tool page -> network, there are a number of requests and traffic statistics of current page. How can I do to record this information (such as log file)?
[traffic statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Z9I.png)

I have reviewed all the documents of QWebEngine and cannot find the corresponding information